# QIBASE driver not loaded

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

Compiled library for qt5.7 [see link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660797/11102). However, I cannot connect it to the project. Please tell me what could be the problem and how do I make it possible?

main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QPluginLoader>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);


    QPluginLoader loader;
    loader.setFileName("/home/alexandr/Qt/5.7/Src/qtbase/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlibase.so");
    qDebug() << loader.load();
    qDebug() <<  loader.isLoaded();
    qDebug() << loader.errorString();

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QIBASE");
    qDebug() << QString("Cannot open database") << db.lastError();

    QCoreApplication::exit(0);
}
```

qibase.pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui
QT += sql

CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = qibase
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

console

```
true
true
"Unknown error"
QSqlDatabase: QIBASE driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
"Cannot open database" QSqlError("", "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you had to use qmake the same version that compiled the plugin qibase after creating the correct Assembly kit the problem disappeared.